# php weird conversion from '/' to '\' + '/'

Tags: php, string, addition

First of all: I'm pretty new to PHP so please excuse me if I'm asking a stupid question.
Recently I came across something strange that I don't understand, no matter how long I research (maybe I was just looking for the wrong keywords).

The following addition of two Strings made the '/' become a '\' + a '/'.
I'm not sure how to handle this and especially I would to know what makes this happen.

```
$curr_path = "storage/";
```

`for($i=0; $i<sizeof($dl_files); $i++) {
        $dl_files[$i] = $curr_path . $dl_files[$i];
}

echo(json_encode($dl_files));  // AJAX server repsonse`

The ouputs are for example ["storage/test.txt"] and I can't figure out where this '\' comes from and how I can get rid of it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you encode that string to json string: `json_encode($dl_files)`, and json specification allows escaping forward slashes.

Comment: Don't worry about it. JSON requires forward slashes to be escaped, and `json_encode()` will do that for you. Any application that reads the JSON and uses a proper decoder, will automatically unescape it so that it becomes just a `/` again.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't think about that ^^
Thank you!